# Functions contains (item,list,cb)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement

So I am supposed to write how this function is supposed to return a cb for true if the item is in the array. I wrote the following but I checked on MDN and it's wrong. It def looks wrong to me but I know I supposed to include return cb() to the equation. What am I doing wrong?

```
 if(===item){
    return cb(true)
  } else {
  return cb(false)
}



  // contains checks if an item is present inside of the given array/list.

  function contains(item, list, cb) {

  // Pass true to the callback if it is, otherwise pass false.
```

I am getting an Unexpected token error in the MDN.

Comment: You might like [`includes()'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the array.includes function to check if item is in the list,you need to invoke the cb passing the parameter true/false.The return value of the callback is would be the return value of the contains function.

```
function contains(item,list,cb){
  if(list.includes(item)){
     return cb(true)
  }
  return cb(false)


 }

contains(3,[1,2,3],function(success){
 if(success){
   return "item is contained in the list"
  }
  return "item is not present in the list"
})
```

Comment: You're a genius. I was just looking at another answer in my class and it is very similar. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Ok you were close but I was still getting an error. You did give me some clarity on the syntax though.

Comment: This is what worked if(list.includes(`${item}`) === true) {
    cb(true)
  } else {
    cb(false)
  }

Comment: Could you specify the parameter with which you are passing to contains.
if(list.includes(item)) should work fine in my opinion.The check === true isn't needed as such.

Comment: Just saying what VS Code is telling me. When I put it in how you gave it I received an error. And of course I can upvote, apologies, new to SO. This is only my second posted question.

Comment: Ok I upvoted but I got a message saying....Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Thanks.. if you don't mind,you could you post the VS code error,I will take a look.

Comment: I've completed that part of the assignment. But I want to say the error was 'undefined' when I typed it in how you gave it to me. There were only minor differences between your code and the code I used. I think I just added the if statement and removed the return keyword, then added the else statement.